# Weird UI/Theme on Ubuntu 20.04 after upgrading from 18.04

Tags: themes, gui, ubuntu-gnome

I got this weird UI in Ubuntu after upgrading from 18.04. After running into an issue with a login loop I somehow managed to upgrade the distribution but got stuck with this UI/theme.

[image: Primary Screen]

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reset the UI to the default with the following command

```
dconf reset -f /
```

As the dconf reset command will reset more than just the Unity, GNOME Shell and MATE desktop you should not run it idly and do make a backup of your existing desktop beforehand, especially if you’ve made extensive customisations and tweaks.

Run `dconf dump`.

Comment: thanks it resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to just to change the theme in gnome-tweaks.

1. Open gnome-tweaks.
2. Navigate to Appearance tab.
3. Choose any theme you like.

You are done! Enjoy!

Comment: Done that but the problem persists besides the top panel is present on the left side of the screen as you can see in the screenshot.